# netbeans (with Qt ) show "unable to resolve identifier" but just for some modules

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, netbeans-7, qt4.8

i using netbeans7.1 with Qt and mingw on win64x .
netbeans show me "unable to resolve identifier"  but just for some modules!
 i checked everythings ( i used a lots of other modules many time they are working )

1. all Qt modules on ( Project Properties -> Build -> Qt Modules )
   are enabled
2. Modules file/header are exists in right place ( i check them with navigate -> Go to Deceleration/Definition Menu )
3. i reBuild project many time, check system PATH .. restart netbeans and etc..
4. **UPDATED:** i tried `Code Assistance`->`Reparse Project`  error was disappear but when i'm building project it's occurs again

**UPDATED(2)**
system environment PATH variables related to netbeans+qt+mingw

```
C:\OSprogramingPack\MinGW\bin;
C:\OSprogramingPack\Qt\4.8.6\bin;
C:\OSprogramingPack\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
```

show me this!

[image]

**UPDATED(3):**
after used  `navigate -> Go to Deceleration/Definition` its directed me to

another file witch its contain #include again , its happened for 3 times!

`"C:\OSprogramingPack\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtNetwork\QSslSocket"`

directed me to

`"C:\OSprogramingPack\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtNetwork\QSslSocket.h"`

and directed again to

`"C:\OSprogramingPack\Qt\4.8.6\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket.h"`

( the orginal header file )

when i open qsslscoket.cpp in  (with `Navigate ->Go to Source`)

`"C:\OSprogramingPack\Qt\4.8.6\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket.cpp"`

shows me :

[image]

Options -> C/C++ -> Build Tools

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about NetBeans 7.1, but in the 8.0.2 I usually do the following: click `Projects` tab, right-click my project name, select `Code Assistance` (pull-down menu will open) and click `Reparse Project`

Comment: @HEKTO: i tried it before , error was disappear  but when i'm building project it's occurs again

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include the socket-related header like below:

```
#include <QtNetwork/QSslSocket>
```

I hope it'll help.

Comment: its still show me  error: 'QSslSocket' was not declared in this scope